# New feature: Add a night mode button?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, dark-mode

I'm using Stack Overflow at night pretty often, and the white background is making my eyes and head hurt when I have to read some big and complex post.

I suggest to add a night mode button that would switch the site to a dark theme.

I have not found this feature in the options so I suppose that it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can use [user stylesheets](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm) for that.

Comment: Or [use f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to alter your display's brightness and color temperature based on the time.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. Though it doesn't seems possible to switch from white to black and then back to white easily.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. But I dont want my hole computer going "screen crazy" ! XD Only stack would be great...

Comment: I believe there are people who maybe might be affected by looking at light so much and they cant keep their eyes in front of a screen for long. This might be of some help. Anyway that is a feature suggestion. You got my upvote

Comment: @OmariOmosa Thank you. Indeed I can't keep my eyes in front of stackOverflow sometimes !

Comment: If that's true, you might need a doctor, @Doctor. I do most of my browsing and programming at night and don't have any problem with my eyes. Of course, having an overhead light on is a *huge* help. Ergonomic specialists have been saying for years that you should never stare at an illuminated screen in a dark room, regardless of whether or not the background is black. Your love of white-on-black themes may also have something to do with your vision problems: "dark" modes have fairly low contrast compared to "light" modes, and therefore strain your eyes.

Comment: @CodyGray My screen is very bright. And I like it like that. But when you have to work realy late and I'm tiered, sometimes I woul'd like, you know... Just make it more pleasant.

Comment: shamelsss lemonplug: [se-chat-dark-theme](https://github.com/rlemon/se-chat-dark-theme-plus)

Comment: _"My screen is very bright. And I like it like that"_ Doesn't seem that way :)

Comment: @CubeJockey Most of the time I do. Like when there is a lot of sun... But on the contrary when its late it becomes a pain in the neck !

Comment: @Doctor: Could you tell, How does this all starts? Do you generally prefer darkness? A small story of some symptoms by the gray background?

Comment: @Oded How would you install a User Style Sheet for SO? Where can you save the custom CSS so that it automatically works with SO/SE (for example with Chrome)?

Comment: @Basj - these days, Chrome recommends using extensions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a desirable feature to add to the site. While it has only a niche market, it would drastically increase development and maintenance costs because now two completely different themes would have to be tested and maintained.

Plus, it simply doesn't scale for every website to have to implement features like this. Should all news websites have a "night" mode? The documentation for your UI library? What about corporate sites? Why doesn't Amazon have this? People shop at night, too.

This is something that would better be handled by the web browser, or perhaps by an application running on your machine. Fortunately, those applications already exist, via [user stylesheets](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow) or [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) and others. Those who want this can get it, without imposing a penalty upon everyone else.

Comment: Adding a switch for the background-color property would not be that hard to maintain. And why talk of other websites ? The subject here is stackoverflow :-). Though you are right that some softwares already exist... But I dont want to install anything else !

Comment: @Doctor Actually, it would *double* all testing efforts for every new change, since it needs to be tested with just not one "skin" but two.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker  I understand that ! But its not like there was that much new front features that needed to be tested each days...

Comment: They add new features all the time. And of course it is not as simple as setting the background color property. Every foreground element, including text, user cards, hyperlinks, flags, and on and on and on would need to have a new color so that it had sufficient contrast with the background.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes you are right. I didn't thought of the contrast.

Comment: @Doctor: Unfortunately, the front-end layout design team is overworked and undermanned, despite significant recruiting efforts; in particular, there's a significant design backlog of months for designing graduated sites' skins on the rest of the network. Doubling the work required, even only on one site (and why not the other 150+?), would significantly add to that load.

Comment: @nathanTuggy I see... But if one day they recruit I hope that they implement this functionnality then ! :-)

Comment: Thats bs, even youtube has night mode. SO is just too lazy to develope it. Whats so hard in writing a new CSS classed and allow users to switch them via a button?!

Comment: So many developers work late into the night on dark-themed IDEs, only to switch to SO and be temporarily blinded. Exaggeration aside, it's still very jarring, even with bluelight filters and dimmed screens. I think a dark-theme would be highly welcomed by the community and could even increase usage.

Comment: Well, they sure showed you, lol.

Comment: Alas, if only this were the first time that what I consider to be an undesirable feature was added to the site, @Chipster.

Answer (score -5):

A feature like this is the responsibility of the hardware or OS, not the content. If the white background hurts your eyes at night, that's not unique to Stack Overflow or any other site with a white background - so you should change the display settings system-wide, not just for one site*.

<sup>* Unless that one site [looks like this](http://www.libertyvan.com/), in which case it should absolutely take responsibility. Eurgh.</sup>

Comment: Yeah, obviously that site needs a dark theme. I only read badly-written pseudo-political rants at night.

Comment: @CodyGray `* {color: black; background-color: black;}` I reckon that would do it.

Comment: You forgot to account for the text in the pictures. A common problem on Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: I know when I am beat, and I shan't continue. Well played sir.

Comment: That site is so cool. I *knew* there had to be an Evangelical equivalent to the [Furthur Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Further_(bus)).

Answer (score -6):

Learn to configure your screen.

No really, I see so many people with brightness and contrast set to 100% all the time. This might look good for movies and games, but doesn't really work well for text. Generally, you want the screen to emit as little light as possible while still being readable. I find that lowering contrast is also useful.

It's unfortunate that many "modern" LCD screens have really shitty controls to do this. I miss the old days with CRT screens and little POD controls.  But there are some software tools to adjust screen brightness; [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) for example can do this (`redshift -b 0.8 -t 6500:6500` to adjust only brightness and not colour temperature).

Comment: The nice thing about using an app to do this is that you can easily return to present configurations. Rarely do you get the best picture by just turning all the dials up to 11, so it's hard to get it back where you want it after turning it down via hardware. Some monitors have "modes," but these are usually preset and therefore suboptimal. (Or maybe I'm the only one who even bothers to color-calibrate their multiple displays.)

Comment: I'm already on the minimum brightness. And it is not my own screen. I can go to my boss and say : "Hey ! Can I get a new screen because this one is too bright." XD !! And I don't feel like installing third-party software.

Comment: @Doctor I find it strange that you say "this is a large problem for me, please fix it!" and then when someone offers a possible solution for you to fix it *yourself* you say "I don't feel like installing third-party software" ...